GCP Healthcheck that accepts non-200 code
Have a use case where I need to check an HTTP web server's health, but need to accept a non-200 code (so 3xx, 4xx, and even 5xx).
I know this isn't possible with HTTP or HTTPS checks, but it seems it is possible with a TCP check:
https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-checks#create-hc
But I can't find any real-world examples, and am not sure on the syntax needed.  I'm trying this:
Request: GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: localhost.localdomain\n
Response: HTTP/1.1
packet captures show the request sent to the web server, but it doesn't show anything in the logs which indicates it doesn't consider this a valid HTTP request.
A basic TCP check isn't adequate because I want to catch cases where the web server is responding to the TCP 3-way handshake, but is unable to return a valid HTTP response.

I'm unable to easily repro. It's unclear from your question whether the Response is your defined (expected) response or whether it's the response you're receiving. I think, it's what you expect. What is your backend receiving? Is it returning anything? The HTTP request should be terminated with a double newline (\n\n). It's unclear whether the Healthcheck will send a newline at the conclusion of the request string but you could try adding a second.

"Response" is what I'm looking to receive from the headers in order to mark the check as successful.  Logs show I'm getting "Timeout before receiving successful response"

Did you try the second newline?
